# Render several image in div Ext.Container.Container

Tags: extjs

How can i Render several image in div EXTJS?

I'm trying to use an `Ext.container.Container` but i only can show one at a time.

Example on at the bottom:

[Example webpage at sencha.com](http://examples.sencha.com/coworkee/#person/9935c919-e077-44f0-a61b-d23ea35a2ad5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your images in `items` array of container, so they will be displayed inside the container. define `flex: 1` in `defaults` so that it will be applied to every member of items array and in `layout` you'll need `type: 'hbox'` to sort them horizontally. You can also shrink the width by help of `width` property.
Here's the [**FIDDLE**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2lj7) (It may not show images on load, so click `Run` for reloading)

Comment: Can you help please with code example of the profile picture with the border.

Comment: Yes, Thank  a  lot for your help.

Comment: Hey friend can you help please again, now with this example http://examples.sencha.com/coworkee/#home

Comment: Open a new question

Comment: Sure, the url is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52562282/ext-container-display-card-of-employee-birthday