# Ext.Container Display Card of Employee Birthday

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm trying to do the following example Employee Birthday locate on this url : http://examples.sencha.com/coworkee/#home , but I do not know to much ext js and their methods or events can someone can help me please.

Comment: You mean this? https://i.imgur.com/sndafRn.png

Comment: Yes , Please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the: [**FIDDLE**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2m74)
Theme on the site(you gave as an example) is `Triton` and it loads fonts itself.
I used [Ext.view.View](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.view.View.html). You must pass [Ext.XTemplate](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.XTemplate.html) and store with data. So you can populate cards.
For styles open `index.html`.
Background color of the iframe(there where view is shown), when you switch to `Triton`, changes to the same color as it was given in your example(`#f5f5f5`) and because of this there difference may can't be seen, so here's the preview:
[image]

**EDIT:**
I made another fiddle where you can populate cards, added some `XTemplate` functions to differ colors and text according to event type:

[**FIDDLE**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2m9t)

Comment: Thanks a lot, for you time!